# elasticsearch pipeline doesn't match paths

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

i'm trying to catch the paths that contains a specified path like
**path/to/my/url/variablePart**,
in the pipeline condition i put
**ctx.url.path == '**path/to/my/url/**'** but unfortunately it takes only the logs that have path/to/my/url/ without considering the other ones with a variable part,
there is a wildcard that can help me to catch every path that start with **'path/to/my/url/'**??
I have already tried to do **ctx.url.path == 'path/to/my/url/*'** but without effect.
thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

A. use a regular expression match:

```
"if": "ctx.url.path =~ /^path\\\/to\\\/my\\\/url\\\//",
```

B. use the `String.indexOf()` function

```
"if": "ctx.url.path.indexOf('path\/to\/my\/url\/') == 0",
```

Comment: can i put it in the condition in the way you wrote ? I need a condition that catches the paths and the GET request, it should work? ctx.url.path.indexOf("path/to/my/url/") == 0 && ctx.http.request.method == 'GET'

Answer (score 0):

this is a peculiar situation, the path must be something like this, but instead set `'ctx.url.path == 'path/to/my/url/*'` i would suggest you to use the percentage % in order to be:
`'ctx.url.path == 'path/to/my/url/%'` this should select all the sub paths in the directory.
If it still gets errors or doesn't respond you correctly, let me know..